# Who is Dracula's son as mentioned in the song Monster Mash?

Tags: horror, dracula

Just been listening to the song [Monster Mash](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNuVifA7DSU) and it mentions Dracula having a son

> The zombies were having fun
> The party had just begun
> The guests included Wolf-Man, **Dracula, and his son**
> The scene was rocking, all were digging the sounds

I've seen a couple of versions of Dracula on screen but I've never read the book....is there a mention in the book of him having any offspring?

Comment: Maybe "and his son" was thrown in simply to rhyme with "having fun", two lines prior. I mean, they could have used "and a hot-cross bun", but that wouldn't have matched the music...

Comment: As for novel Dracula having a son, at one point is mentioned that he has descendants, possibly down to the present time.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The song’s references are often based on popular movies from the previous thirty years rather than on books.

This is likely a reference to the 1943 film [*Son of Dracula*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_of_Dracula_(1943_film)), which starred Lon Chaney, Jr.

Comment: Lon Caney Jr also played the Wolf Man in a few films.

Comment: And while this is almost certainly correct, can you offer any proof or evidence?

Comment: @Valorum The Wikipedia link isn’t good enough for you?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I'm not doubting that there was a film called *Son of Dracula*. I'm wanting proof that **that's what the song is referring to**.

Comment: Sadly, [the author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobby_Pickett#:~:text=Pickett%20died%20of%20leukemia%20on,%2C%202007%2C%20at%20age%2069.) died in 2007, so we can't ask him. :-/

Comment: And [the other author](https://wiggles.fandom.com/wiki/Leonard_Capizzi) died in 1988.

Comment: The classic monster movie trio (Dracula, Frankenstein, Wolfman) got lots of spinoff sequels: son of, bride of, etc.  This is the phenomenon "Young Frankenstein" is a parody of.

Comment: @Valorum The question is whether a son is mentioned in the book. And this answer is accepted.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - That seems very reductive. I assumed that OP wanted to know what the song was referring to, not just whether Dracula had a son in the source novel. Notably, this answer doesn't actually answer that question either.

Comment: @Valorum no, I have no proof or evidence, and will gladly defer to anyone who does. But I suspected the OP was unaware of this film, which even in the 1960s was probably the obvious reference (correct or not).

Comment: @JamesMcLeod - Hmm. You might perhaps mention that the eponymous ['Monster mash' was a style of film made famous by Universal Pictures](https://www.denofgeek.com/movies/monster-mash-musical-universal-monsters-news/), lending credence to the idea that Picket is referencing Universal characters; https://archive.org/details/Monsters_of_the_Movies_005_Curtis_1975_Vigilante407/page/n32/mode/1up

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that the film Son of Dracula is the origin of the name 'Alucard' for Dracula's son, which has been referenced by other media since then (especially Castlevania and Hellsing)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots So? Dracula died in 1476, and he's still making movies today.  You'd think Picket and Capizzi could at least do a few *interviews* from beyond the grave.

Comment: @Ray - You'll need to speak to their agents. Now those are the *real* bloodsuckers...